# Android viewmodel observing always

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-viewmodel, koin

I am using `KoinDI` and I have a login screen. Here is my code -

My AppModule code which shows `LoginViewModel` DI definition -

```
private val viewModelModules = module {
    viewModel { LoginViewModel(get()) }
}
```

My `LoginFragment` code -

```
private val viewModel: LoginViewModel by viewModel()

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    view.login_button?.setOnClickListener {
        onLoginButtonPressed()
    }
}

private fun onLoginButtonPressed() {
        val email = view?.email_value?.text.toString()
        val password = view?.password_value?.text.toString()

        viewModel.onLoginPressed(email, password).observe(this, Observer {

                if (it.userLoggedIn) {
                    //...
                }
                handleError(it.error)

        })
}
```

The problem is when I click login and immediately put the app in background and API call fails (I fail it on purpose 
for testing from the backend side) and when I bring the app in foreground I see
that the viewmodel continues to observe resulting in API call happening again and again until it succeeds. Why does it happen?
Why cannot my viewmodel observe only on login button click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say `viewModel.onLoginPressed.observe` the activity/fragment will receive events when it is `started` or `resumed` state and when it is destroyed the observer will automatically be removed.

You seem to have a retry logic inside the `viewModel` that keep retrying.

Comment: You are absolutely right...I had made a silly mistake of retry logic. Thank you

Comment: Glad I could be of help